# Implementation of an own message dispatcher in C

Tags: c

I want to make my own message dispatcher in C... 
For example, I want to send a message to MyButton or MyWindow structures. 
And these structures have their own handlers.

Have any gurus any suggestions?

PS: for embedded application (using microcontroller)

PPS: thanks to **sean** - this is what I need.
My simple interpretation of sean's advice:

```
typedef void (*MyHandler)(size_t param);
MyHandler Handlers[32];
void RegisterHandlers(size_t id, MyHandler handler) {
  Handlers[id] = handler;   
}
void SendMessage(size_t id, size_t param) {
  Handlers[id](param);  
}
```

Comment: For what desktop environment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I fear this question will be closed because it is rather broad and doesn't have a single good answer (or even a small range of good answers).  You've also not really given enough context to explain what `MyButton` or `MyWindow` structures might be doing with the messages, etc.  At some point soon, please read the [FAQ].

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Tell us more about the natue of the targets of the messages. Are you looking to send the message synchronously (and wait for a response) or asynchronously (fire and forget)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this I would do the following:

Design a thread safe container for the events that are fired, a queue.

Then I would design a system to tie an event id, string or a integer, to a function through way of a hash table or some other mechanism like that.

After these two chunks are made you just need a way to register event id's with a function pointer and then just have a common way to send parameters to the functions and that's pretty much all there needs to be done with a message dispatcher. You push messages to the queue and then you pop things off the queue and react to whatever the message contains.